# Can't access passed object variable in re-used ng-template

Tags: angular, scope, ng-template

Looping over a JSON object in order to render it as HTML in my Component Template. Re-using a inline ng-template for outputting the HTML.

From the first iteration I am not able to access the Ojbect properties on `level` since it is `undefined`, however, the output HTML-like tree structure is build up exactly as the JSON is. Seems like i'm not passing the oject variable in the correct order.

JSON

```
    { "content": [
            {
                "tag": "paragraph",
                "html": "\r\n",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "tag": "header",
                        "level": "1",
                        "html": "\r\n91\/439\/EC Driving Licences"
                    },
                    {
                        "tag": "header",
                        "level": "2",
                        "html": "\r\nANNEX II - chapter II"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "tag": "br"
            },
            {
                "tag": "paragraph",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "tag": "table",
                        "html": "\r\n",
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "tag": "tr",
                                "children": [
                                    {
                                        "tag": "td",
                                        "html": "II    ."
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "tag": "td",
                                        "html": "\r\nMember States may implement the appropriate measures to ensure that drivers who have lost the knowledge, skills and behaviour as described under points 1 to 9 can recover this knowledge and these skills and will continue to exhibit such behaviour required for driving a motor vehicle.",
                                        "children": [
                                            {
                                                "tag": "br"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "tag": "br"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "tag": "list",
                                                "type": "disc",
                                                "html": "\r\n",
                                                "children": [
                                                    {
                                                        "tag": "li",
                                                        "html": "Recognise traffic dangers and assess their seriousness;"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "tag": "li",
                                                        "html": "Have sufficient command of their vehicle not to create dangerous situations and to react appropriately should such situations occur;"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "tag": "li",
                                                        "html": "Comply with road traffic regulations, and in particular those intended to prevent road accidents and to maintain the flow of traffic;"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "tag": "li",
                                                        "html": "Detect any major technical faults in their vehicles, in particular those posing a safety hazard, and have them remedied in an appropriate fashion;"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "tag": "li",
                                                        "html": "Take account of all the factors affecting driving behaviour (e.g. alcohol, fatigue, poor eyesight, etc.) so as to retain full use of the faculties needed to drive safely;"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "tag": "li",
                                                        "html": "Help ensure the safety of all road users, and in particular of the weakest and most exposed by showing due respect for others."
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Template

```
<div *ngFor="let rootLevel of jsonHTML; let i = index;">
  <span *ngIf="rootLevel.tag">{{i}} [{{rootLevel.tag}}]</span {{rootLevel.html}}

    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="nextLevelTemplate; context: { level: rootLevel.children, index: i }">
    </ng-container>

</div>

<ng-template #nextLevelTemplate let-level="level" let-i="index">

  <span *ngIf="level && level.tag">[{{level.tag}}]</span><span *ngIf="level && level.html">[{{level.html}}]</span>

  [tag]{{level?.tag}}[/tag] 

  [html]{{level?.html}}[/html]

  -{{level | json}}-

  <div *ngFor="let nextLevel of level; let i = index;">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="nextLevelTemplate; context: { level: nextLevel.children, index: i }">
    </ng-container>
  </div>

</ng-template>
```

Output

```
0 [paragraph] 
  0 -[object Object],[object Object]-
    0 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --
    1 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --

1 [br] 1 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --

2 [paragraph] 2 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] -[object Object]-
  0 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] -[object Object]-
    0 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] -[object Object],[object Object]-
      0 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --
      1 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] -[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]-

      0 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --
      1 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --
      2 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] -[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]-
        0 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --
        1 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --
        2 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --
        3 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --
        4 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --
        5 [tag][/tag] [html][/html] --
```

Output and screenshot of the following JSON node

```
"children": [
  {
    "tag": "header",
    "level": "1",
    "html": "\r\n91\/439\/EC Driving Licences"
  },
  {
    "tag": "header",
    "level": "2",
    "html": "\r\nANNEX II - chapter II"
  }
]
```

[image]

As you can see there are 2 items in the Array, template loops over it twice, but `tag` and `html` properties cant be accessed.

Is this is scoping issue, that ng-template cant be re-used in this way?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question is: [Recursive ng-template references](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3512-playing-with-recursive-ng-template-references-in-angular-6-1-10.htm)

Indeed a scoping issue. Its, obviously, all about passing around scope in the right way.

```
<!-- Define the recursive template. -->
<ng-template #nodeTemplateRef let-node>

    <div class="node" [class.node--selected]="( node === selectedTreeNode )">

        <a (click)="selectNode( node )" class="node__label">
            {{ node.label }}
        </a>

        <div *ngIf="node.children.length" class="node__children">

            <!-- Invoke the recursive template. -->
            <ng-template
                ngFor
                [ngForOf]="node.children"
                [ngForTemplate]="nodeTemplateRef">
                <!--
                    NOTE: The "$implicit" property of the ngFor context is what will
                    be made available to the template ref's implicit let-node binding.
                -->
            </ng-template>

        </div>

    </div>

</ng-template>

<ng-template
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="nodeTemplateRef"
    [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: data.root }">
</ng-template>

<p class="note">
    <em>Ng-For Template Rendering</em>
</p>
```

...the ngFor directives was successfully able to recursively render the ngTemplate in which it was defined.

When using the ngFor directive, there's no way to explicitly pass-in a "context" object - the ngFor directive implicitly passes-in the ngForContext object as the template context. This means that my ng-template directive has to use the "implicit" export of the ngFor context as the "let-node" template binding.

In this case, that's not an issue since I only want to pass-in the one value. But, for more flexibility, we can forgo the ngFor directive and simply use another ng-template to render the template recursively (in much the same way that we use an ng-template instance to initiate the recursion)...